# Launcher compatibility issue with my android app

Tags: android, launcher

The issue is, when I install NovaLauncher and press the Home button, selection of launcher keeps popping up, even when I have clicked 'Always' every time. In settings of NovaLauncher, there is a disclaimer "The app may cause your default launcher to be reset frequently". Has someone fixed this issue?

This also happens with FitPro app.

When i installed more than 1 launcher, this happens.

Here is a detailed description of what's happening. But this link only gives answer for digital wellbeing, here my app is causing this issue.

https://gist.github.com/bengalih/ee939232fcde3c22516134e10cabbf11

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This happens because of the FitPro app. We are working on a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have this problem because of the FitPro app, here is the solution:

1. Remove the watch from FitPro
2. Install Hi Watch Pro from Google play.
3. Uninstall FitPro.

Tested on Android 12, it works.

For those who still have problems, try the app Da Fit or Da Fit pro after removing.

Last but not least download the app from here:
https://fitpro.en.uptodown.com/android

It works for me.